# Recurring Task Closed(Completed)

Tags: account, tasks, task-recurrence

I have one question related to the salesforce standard functionality Recurring Task.

I have created one custom field "status" on the standard object Account and it has two value 1) Open 2) Completed.

I have also manually created one Recurring task on that account records.

I need to closed all that Recurring tasks when particular records field value is "completed".

Is there any way to achieve this one with standard workflow rules or process builder??

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

Using the process builder you should be able to update the related tasks on the Account that started the Process. The question is what makes a Task closed? Doe you set the status to closed? Do you set the recurring end date to the date the Account was updated to Completed? That is a business decision you will need to make, but you will be able to update the related tasks on the Account using the process builder.

A good place to start learning about the process builder is trailhead or reading up on the documentation.

Trailhead Link: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/business_process_automation/units/process_builder

Process Builder Documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_overview.htm&type=0